# Weka predictive value of attributes

Tags: weka

I've got a question about finding the predictive value of certain attributes.
In my question it is suggested that I transform my attributes to binary classes and then apply "decision stump" to find out the predictive value of each attribute. How do I do this?

I checked out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927269/filtering-attributes-with-weka) But that's not really what I mean.

Thanks in advance, Rope.

Comment: What kinds of attributes are you working with? Transforming a `nominal` to a binary class will be different than transforming a `numeric`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the most predictive attributes using the methods found under the `Select Attributes` tab in Weka's `Explorer`.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the Select Attributes tab in Weka analyzes your attributes and ranks which ones provide the most information gain. Under Attribute Evaluator, choose InfoGainAttributeEval and choose Ranker for search method. It works quite well in my experience.